# Select rows from MySQL where data is not the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have a chat system and a topbar with notifications
What i want to do is load the last message from the last X persons the user has chatted
So i dont want to spam the notifications with X number of messages from the same person but i want to load the very LAST message from X number of persons

So here is my problem (example):
Imagine if one person sent the user 8 messages and i limit the message query to 8 results. The query will return 8 messages from the same person but i've made a PHP filter that will echo only 1 message from one person. So basically this will only echo 1 message from 1 person but wont echo any other messages from any other person because ive limited the result query to 8 and this user already spammed 8 messages

This is my PHP filter (but i want to do this in SQL)

```
foreach ($sideMess as $smes) {
    if (!isset($showedList[$smes['id']])) { 
        echo '<div class="mes_wrap" id="ppl_', $smes['id'] ,'">
            <img src="', $smes['avatar'] ,'">
            <h4>', $smes['firstname'] ,' ', $smes['lastname'] ,'</h4>
            </div>';

        $showedList[$smes['id']] = true;
        $cS ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the db schema and what query are you using.

Comment: So if you limit is `X = 3` and only one person post 5 messages. Do you want last 3 messages or just 1 (the newest). And if two person post 5 messages same `X = 3`?

Comment: Just do a group by submitting user.

Comment: `select user, max(message_time) as last_msg from messages where receiver=_ and message_time > now() - interval 3 day group by user order by last_msg desc limit 8` gives the users, and then go for each of the 8 users and find the last message.

Comment: We don't know your DB schema but basically, you can do a query to get the most recent messages from X users by adding `GROUP BY submittinguser LIMIT X` at the end.

Comment: which field you use to identify `last message`?

Comment: This is my DB shema (i select the last message by the date UNIX timestamp) http://prntscr.com/8chri4

Answer (score 1):

As per your specification, it seems that you want list of last message from multiple users, i.e, user-wise last message.

```
select * from
(select * from
messages
order by user_id,message_time desc) temp
group by user_id;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "temp" and why are you selecting 2 times?

Comment: @Champa : I need data in specific order. `temp` is just run-time memory/temporary table. Does the query give the output you want..?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, its solved!
I used GROUP BY sender_id before ORDER BY
Thanks for your help!